# Scipy stats probability greater than 1

Tags: python, precision, distribution, scipy.stats

I am computing values of a binomial probability mass function and find that their sum exceeds 1 when passing extreme parameters to the pmf.

See for example:

```
from scipy.stats import binom
n = 1541096362225563.0
p = 1.0477878413173978e-18
vals = [binom.pmf(n=n, p=p, k=i) for i in range(3)]
print(vals)  # -> [0.9983865609638467, 1.0, 0.060730098812886574]
```

I can see how I might filter out the 1.0 as an error, but even the rest of the values sum up to more than 1. For my purpose, I do not mind numerical imprecision of the sort of `np.finfo(np.float16).eps`, but the example is clearly more extreme. Is there a good way to deal with this?

Comment: That's an extremely small probablity, are you sure its right & not itself a rounding error of somekind?

Comment: I guess in many cases this would be unnaturally low for a Binomial - In my case the probabilities are indeed that low, but that just goes to show that a Binomial may no longer be the most natural description of the distribution, as the accepted answer suggests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For such extremely small `p` and extremely large `n` I'd suggest trying a [Poisson approximation to the binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Poisson_approximation), where the rate λ is `n*p`. That brings the parameterization up to a level where you're not stressing the limits of floating point arithmetic.

```
from scipy.stats import poisson
n = 1541096362225563.0
p = 1.0477878413173978e-18
lmbd = n * p
vals = [poisson.pmf(k=i, mu=lmbd) for i in range(3)]
print(vals)  # -> [0.9983865609638467, 0.0016121367428128667, 1.3015924788782268e-06]
```

The only other alternative I can see would be to implement the binomial calculations yourself with rationals, but that would get computationally very expensive.

Comment: Ah, that's an excellent solution! A lot more elegant to do the statistical approximation than worrying about machine precision. Thank you!